# Where should date representation should be handled on API or on mobile app?

Tags: android, api, mobile

We have API which that return some dates 
And we have mobile app that use this dates but it represent  this dates in different formats like ( 10 mins ago )
So what is best way to handle the representation of date 
On API or from mobile app ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be able to change the representation without redeploying / re-releasing the app you should represent it on the server.

Alternatively you could represent it in UTC on the server and have each client of the API responsible for displaying the information based on their own needs. This places more responsibility on the client, but keeps the server ignorant of display concerns.

Answer (score 0):

you can also get the reference of current time via `currentTime - difference` then calcualte the actual time to display properly through `SimpleDateFormat` API, although its better to handle it on server side using UTC time.

you can calculate the current time through [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) API